# How to create per section variable that is readable in same-section formula in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

Good morning,

I am struggling to find a solution to my Crystal Reports problem and am hoping someone here can help me out :)

I am trying to identify in which detail section (detail a or detail b) a formula is being executed. Idea is to have a global stringvar as identifier in each section that changes value with section change. And then use this stringvar in a formula within that section.

```js
//formula a
global stringvar section:="a"

//formula b
stringvar section:="b"

//formula test
stringvar section;
local numbervar test;

If section="a" Then
    test:=1
Else If section="b" Then
    test:=2;
test
```

However, the stringvar section is being shown correctly in each section but the result of test is always the same (that for the second section.

[image]

[image]

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong and how I can solve it?

Thank you for your help :)

Alex

Comment: I don't know the programming language behind this, but I'll still try to help. You defined your variable stringvar and set it to a first, then to b. So section is now always b. Therefore it always goes into the second if branch and displays 2 for every solution. You need to change your variable dynamically. Or you make an array ( or list ) containing all sections and then print the results according to your if branch. Hope this gives you some ideas

Comment: Unfortunately Crystal Reports does not have a way of telling which section the formula is in. So if I create an array with two values, both values will always be declared just like in my current approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare the ***section*** variable in all the formulas as **global**.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that each formula is evaluated only once per record -- not once per section. So the test formula, which is used in 2 different detail sections would return the same value in both sections.

I'm not aware of a way to force a formula to evaluate again for each split section, even if you add a *WhilePrintingRecords* directive.

Bottom line: look for a completely alternative strategy. If you need different content in each section, simply place different content in each section.

Comment: That's the issue. I essentially have 20 formulas of which 10 are duplicates with only one input value changed. A 2 liner if expression would halve the amount of code. So I am looking for a way, any way, to determine in which detail section it is being called. Any solution would do.